# avoid rectangle to overlay axes

Tags: r, plot

Suppose data are

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:9,y=2:10)
```

which I plot

```
plot(0, col="white", xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ylab="")
rect(3,0,5,10, col="gray", border=NA)
lines(dat$x, dat$y)
```

but the rectangle overlays the axes.

[image: close up]

I could draw them (and the box) again but  I wonder whether there is a more parsimonious way of achieving the same result. I thought of subtracting a line width from the heights of the rectangle but wouldn't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `panel.first` in the plot call:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=1:9,y=2:10)

plot(dat, type = "l", xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ylab="", 
panel.first = rect(3,0,5,10, col =  "gray", border = NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>